# Disable the css3 transitions in Flexslider?

Tags: jquery, css, flexslider

Does anyone know how to disable the CSS3 transitions in Flexslider v2?
I've been told you can disable them, but can't see how to do so.

Currently the transitions are possibly causing clashes with video.js in Safari for ipad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it; I set 'useCSS: false' and 'video: true'. This disabled the transitions, but sadly there still seems to be a clash somewhere that's stopping the videos working.

Back to the drawingboard!